# Connection issues with fxcmpy REST api

Tags: python, forex, python-socketio

I am using the REST api from fxcmpy to connect to my fxcmpy account.
Since the upgrade to version 1.2.6, I have issues with reconnection when I am accidentally deconnected from the server.

I detect deconnection through the command

```
api.socket.on('disconnect',disconnect)
```

where disconnect is my callback function where I reconnect :

```
def disconnect():
    FLAG=False
    while not FLAG:
    try :
        api=fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token=API_ACCESS_TOKEN,log_level='error',server='demo')
        api.subscribe_market_data(symbol,(automated_strategy,))
        FLAG=True
    except:
        print('be patient')
        time.sleep(60)
        FLAG=False
```

Since the new version I get either a "ServerError: Can not connect to FXCM Server." or a "packet queue is empty, Aborting" message.

If I restart my python console, I can restart my script until the next disconnection.
I tried this on Windows 10, Raspbian and android : same issue in all the cases.

I have updated both python-socketio and python-engineio to their latest version : no change.

I am looking for a way of restarting the client when I have disconnection issues. Does someone have the same issue / a clue to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi I have the same issue, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it took me a while, but I finally found a workaround. The idea is to reset completely the fxcmpy librairy : remove it and then import it again.

Here is how I do that (code is still not optimized, you can improve it but the idea is here) :

> ```
> while not FLAG:
>     try :
>         import sys
>         a_del=[]
>         for module in sys.modules.keys():
>             if 'fxcm' in module:
>                 a_del.append(module)
>
>         for module in a_del:
>             del sys.modules[module]
>
>         del fxcmpy
>
>     except:
>         print('error in reinitialization')
>     try:
>         del api
>     except:
>         print('could not delete api')
>
>     try :
>         import fxcmpy
>         api=fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token=API_ACCESS_TOKEN,log_level='error',server='demo')
>         api.subscribe_market_data(symbol,(automated_strategy,))
>
>         FLAG=True
>     except:
>         print('try again')
>         time.sleep(10)
>         FLAG=False
> ```

this should do it (adapt of course your api object name and automated strategy function name).

Comment: Actually, I mistakenly opened two connections, after that I am getting my connection aborted. Tried running your code, but I am still getting connection aborted. What I should do?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to reinstalling the fxcmpy module, installing "python-socketio" worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Working on the same problem these days. I guess the problem is that the session needs to be closed before opening a new.

Something like:

```
def disconnect():
global api


try:
    api.close()
except:
    pass

FLAG=False
while not FLAG:
    try :
        api=fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token=API_ACCESS_TOKEN,log_level='error',server='demo')
        api.subscribe_market_data(symbol,(automated_strategy,))
        FLAG=True
    except:
        print('be patient')
        time.sleep(60)
        FLAG=False
```

I am curious about how you override the disconnect callback function when you need to. for instance when doing KeyboardIntterupt and SystemExit?